# offline authentication with ldap, pam-ccreds and nss_updatedb

Tags: authentication, ldap, debian, pam

I've setup a linux machine (debian 6.0.7) with ldap authentication with the following configurations:

/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:         compat ldap [NOTFOUND=return UNAVAIL=continue] db
group:          compat ldap [NOTFOUND=return UNAVAIL=continue] db
shadow:         compat ldap
```

/etc/pam.d/common-account

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
account [user_unknown=ignore authinfo_unavail=ignore default=ok]        pam_unix.so
account [success=ok user_unknown=ignore authinfo_unavail=ignore default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 debug
account [success=done default=ignore authinfo_unavail=1]     pam_ldap.so debug
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
account requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
account required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

/etc/pam.d/common-auth

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=done default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    requisite       pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet
auth    requisite       pam_succeed_if.so gid >= 1000 quiet
auth    requisite       pam_succeed_if.so user notingroup root
auth    requisite       pam_succeed_if.so user notingroup wheel
auth    [success=3 default=2 authinfo_unavail=ignore]      pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_ccreds.so minimum_uid=1000 action=validate use_first_pass
auth    [default=ignore]                pam_ccreds.so minimum_uid=1000 action=update
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional                        pam_ccreds.so minimum_uid=1000 action=store
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

/etc/pam.d/common-password

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
password        [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512
password        [success=1 user_unknown=ignore default=die authinfo_unavail=ignore]     pam_ldap.so try_first_pass
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
password        required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
password        optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

/etc/pam.d/common-session

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
session [default=1]                     pam_permit.so
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
session requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
session required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
session required        pam_unix.so
session required        pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0022
session optional        pam_ldap.so
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

in common-account I had to jump to pam_permit if ldap server is unavailable otherwise users with cached credentials can't authenticate, but I think this is not a good idea.

I'm also running nss_updatedb ldap to cache passwd and groups.

Everything is working fine, even offline authentication. The problem is when I disable a user on ldap (setting shadowexpire to 1). When the machine is online authentication system notify that the account is disabled but when the machine is offline a disabled user can login using cached credentials. I believe it's because shadow infos aren't cached.

Is it a way to cache shadow informations about disabled users so they can't log in even when the machine is offline?

Answer (score 0):

pam_ccreds README says this isn't currently supported.  You could reset the user's password instead of using shadowexpire.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing your config! I changed `/etc/pam.d/common-account` from

```
account [user_unknown=ignore authinfo_unavail=ignore default=ok]        pam_unix.so
```

to

```
account [success=done user_unknown=ignore authinfo_unavail=ignore default=ok]        pam_unix.so
```

The problem was that when the LDAP server was not available a local user was turned down even with a good password. *success=done* terminates the chain once pam_unix.so says it is ok.